# Воссоздание объектов в юнити по примеру

Tags: c#, unity3d

появилась идея сделать скрипт, что будет "воксилизировать" модель, во благо оптимизации и личного интереса собственно.
Пришел сюда вот по какому вопросу, возможно ли в юнити вообще, воссоздать объект находящийся например внутри коллайдера? грубо говоря точную его копию, только собрать из кусочков, как лего.
Например у меня есть куча частей локации, и есть целая локация, возможно ли сделать так, чтобы юнити как ксерокс "считал" модель, и воспроизвел ее примерно в том же виде, но из отдельных тайлов?
Предупрежу сразу всех умников, я не прошу НАПИСАТЬ мне скрипт, я лишь желаю узнать существует ли такое, ибо в гугле я толком ничего не нашел кроме как процедурная генерация, но мне же не это надо.
А банальное дублирование не подходит, ибо каков тогда смысл самого скрипта (и нет, не стоит спрашивать каков его смысл если он будет просто превращать все в кубики, весь смысл описан выше).
Может у кого документация где-то завалялась, в которой что-то хотя-бы ПОХОЖЕЕ есть? или я совсем уже еду с катушек и такого впринципе существовать конкретно в юнити не может?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Существует? Если и да, то вряд ли в общем доступе как отдельный бесплатный скрипт.

Возможно ли написать? Да, возможно. И, как раз таки, через процедурную генерацию. Собственно, как ты без генерации обьектов собираешся получить воксельную поверхность? Это как попросить налить кастрюлю жидкости без использования жидкости)

Примером платного ассета может быть: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/mesh-voxelizer-150233

Но вообще существуют воксельные игрвые движки (Voxel Farm например). У них идет оптимизация под воксели и, вероятнее всего, уже есть даный функционал из коробки.

Comment: понял, благодарю, насчет других движков, я просто хочу как либо внедрить это в юнити если такого еще нет, видел уже на других, а на юнити ничего подобного не нашел.
Видимо на отпимизацию любят положить большой и толстый, раз до сих пор на ютубе таких роликов нет, как и в гугле статей на эту тему.
Причем это не просто пустая оптимизация, к тому же это еще больше возможностей к разрушениям, я не думаю что объект 10к на 10к вокселей, будет нагружать систему сильнее, чем объект 10к на 10к полигонов

Comment: Ты явно слабо представляешь что такое воксель. Нагружать будет больше, потому что один воксель это 16 полигонов. То есть нагрузка разнится в 16 раз. Оптимизациями можно добится лучших результатов, например часть вокселей до поры до времени отрисовывать одним большим вокселем. Но это все равно не даст разительного уменьшения нагрузки ибо это хоть и уменьшает количество полигонов(в вокселях), но и заставляет вести перерасчет размеров вокселей и перерасчет текстурных разверток. То есть нагрузка все равно будет ЗНАЧИТЕЛЬНО больше на вокселях.

Comment: 4 полигона, начнем с этого.
Почему 4? да потому что не в треугольниках они.
(максимум 12 , по 3 на сторону)

на отрисовку на большом расстоянии от обьекта уйдет куда меньше, ибо "например часть вокселей до поры до времени отрисовывать одним большим вокселем" , я так же думал , а в целом, я не думаю что это займет овермного, можно сделать по 1 полигону на каждую сторону.

и тут 2 варианта, либо модельки будут более "квадратные" и смотрется будет не очень, либо будет жрать чуть больше но все же.

в любом случае количество полигонов снизить труда не составит, и сделать красиво (имхо).

Comment: Ну да, 12, а не 16. Но не 4. Это для тебя полигоны прямоугольные в вьюпорте, а для видеокарты они ВСЕГДА треугольные.  Хочешь проверить что они треугольные? Зайди в любой 3д редактор и создай 4хугольник одним полигоном. А потом перемести один вертекс по оси перпендикулярной к плоскости полигона.  Для того что бы было лучше видно - сделай "хард сарфейс" полигон, тогда не будет сглаживания и ты увидишь истинную форму полигона -- не смотря на то что во вьюпорте ты будешь видеть 4угольный полигон, на самом деле это 2 треугольных. Так что "начнем из этого" не работает.

Comment: попробуем, посмотрим.
говорю так уверенно потому что проверял, так что.
возможно я и не прав и отрицать этого не стану